# MVC3 same ViewModel used for two cases with Required attribute in only one case

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a ViewModel. something like this

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int? Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have a table of existing ViewModels, and below that I have a form where you can add a new ViewModel

For existing ViewModels that are fetched from DB i want no validation on the Value property, but for the case when adding a new ViewModel I want required validation.... The real model is more complex then this one so I want to use the same model in both cases.. Is it possible?

**edit: this works**

```
public class AddNewViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public new int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Is it better to use `new` or `virtual/override` and why?

Comment: You can use the new keyword instead of virtual or override, but I don't think you would get polymorphism in this case. So, if you cast AddNewViewModel as a ViewModel, your Value from AddNewViewModel would not make it into the newly cast ViewModel.

Comment: That is not a problem, I do not put the AddNewViewModel into the ViewModel collecton, its a own property on the Parent ViewModel.. Question is if my solution with new keyword is better than olivehour with override

Comment: I think new should be okay, but I have modified your question to ask this because I'm not sure. I try to avoid new because to me it smells, but that may just be my opinion, and not necessarily "correct".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required attributes are compiled into the class. You could do something like this:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual int? Value { get; set; }
}

public class CreateViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   [Required]
   public override int? Value { get; set; }
}
```

This way, you only add the validation attribute to the properties where you need them.

Comment: THats exactly what I did, se my edit D edit: Not exatly, you did it with override

Comment: I think I was writing my answer while you were writing your edit. I added comment after I saw it.